# Using Match.Create in Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I've got a strange behavior when using `Match.Create` with Moq.

The following code snippet doesn't pass, when I extract `Match.Create` as a variable:

```
      var mock = new Mock<IA>();
      mock.Object.Method ("muh");
      mock.Verify (m => m.Method (Match.Create<string> (s => s.Length == 3)));

      public interface IA
      {
        void Method (string arg);
      }
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks both of you. But I found another good solution for this. As in the [quick start](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) described, you can also use a method. First I thought it would make no difference, whether I use a variable or method. But obviously Moq is clever enough. So the expression and predicate stuff can be converted into:

```
public string StringThreeCharsLong ()
{
  return Match.Create<string> (s => s.Length == 3);
}
```

I think this is great, because it reduces the noise in unit tests.

```
MyMock.Verify (m => m.Method (StringThreeCharsLong());
```

Comment: +1: This is indeed the cleanest way to refactor such case - you should mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

You're extracting too much. Predicate is enough:

```
var mock = new Mock<IA>();
Predicate<string> isThreeCharsLong = s => s.Length == 3;
mock.Object.Method("muh");
mock.Verify(m => m.Method(Match.Create<string>(isThreeCharsLong)));
```

Alternatively, for the same effect but slightly shorter syntax you can use `It.Is` matcher with expression parameter:

```
var mock = new Mock<IA>();
Expression<Func<string, bool>> isThreeCharsLong = s => s.Length == 3;
mock.Object.Method("muh");
mock.Verify(m => m.Method(It.Is<string>(isThreeCharsLong)));
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** Got your question wrong, again:

The problem is that `Match.Create<string> (s => s.Length == 3);` returns a string. 
It can only be used inside the `.Verify()` call. The same happens with `It.Is<string>(Expr)`, if you extract a variable it will be passed as a simple System.String, and verify will check against that as a value (and fail because that value will be just String.Empty)

```
var mock = new Mock<IA>();

//this will be a string, and contain just ""
var yourMatcher = Match.Create<string> (s => s.Length == 3);

mock.Object.Method ("muh");

//this will fail because "muh" != ""
mock.Verify (m => m.Method (yourMatcher));

public interface IA
{
  void Method (string arg);
}
```